# My html 5 video seems to stop after .5 of a second

Tags: html, video

My html 5 video seems to stop after .5 of a second. It has autoplay enabled, but is muted. Also the controls seem to continue when they're enabled, even thought the video isn't playing.

Heres the link: http://tmwlsh.co.uk/bedrock/

Answer (score 0):

This behavior could be due to multiple problems:

- the video-file could be corrupted beyond 5 sec
- your server has a limitation on the file size
- Wordpress plugin is paid and only shows 5 sec. promo

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is with your video itself - if you download the video and look at in in an editor you will see that the video is blank after the first 5 seconds.

Your HTML5 and the website look like they are behaving fine.

Answer (score 0):

All i can see is a broken video. So i think you should fix that. When you download the video it also stops after like 2 - 3 seconds.